# facebook, php, what is the url to get the news feed of current user?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My code is like this:

```
$FBpage = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token='.$params['access_token']);
$FBdata = json_decode($FBpage);
```

The problem is that the "feed" returned contains only a small part of the information (a few friend adds and no posts with links).
What is the url to get the home page news feed of current user? It can be pretty big so if you can also tell me how to get a certain number of feed entries or how to "page" through it.

I don't have problems with login or other, I am able to get the data just that I think the url is not the one I want.
This is a basic question but however I just don't find info on google.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook's documentation can be kinda misleading.  Note there are multiple connections to the user object.  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

- **feed**: The user's wall.
- **home**: The user's news feed.

LOL, when you call `/me/feed`, you're really getting the **user's wall**.  when you call `/me/home` this is when you really get the **new feed**.  Facebook likes to make it harder than it really is.

Note: some other ways to get `stream` items from a user graph object

- **links**: The user's posted links.
- **posts**: The user's own posts
- **statuses**: The user's status updates.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google revealed this guy's instructions:
http://johndoesdesign.com/blog/2011/php/adding-a-facebook-news-status-feed-to-a-website/

"4)  You can then access the Facebook data feed as JSON data at the following URL: ’https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN’, replacing PAGE_ID with your page, group or profile ID, and ACCESS_TOKEN with the Access Token you were given in step 3.
Note:  Your page, group or profile ID can be found in its URL.  Eg. ’http://www.facebook.com/group.php?gid=102037668290′, the ID would be the numbers after the ‘gid?=’.

5)  You can then display the feed using a little PHP.. something like this:

```
<?php
//Get the contents of the Facebook page
$FBpage = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN');
//Interpret data with JSON
$FBdata = json_decode($FBpage);
//Loop through data for each news item
foreach ($FBdata->data as $news )
{
//Explode News and Page ID's into 2 values
$StatusID = explode("_", $news->id);
echo '<li>'
//Check for empty status (for example on shared link only)
if (!empty($news->message)) { echo $news->message;}
echo '</li>'
}
?>
```

Not sure if that helps, as it's pretty much what you've been doing. But he does say that this should get you standard text updates etc, as well, just no media content.
"

Comment: I am already doing this. The problem is the urls i tried https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=.. and https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/feed?access_token=.. return only a few feeds (actually only friend acceptance info) but no posts with links. Maybe it's some security setting, or I am missing something.